# How to get button id in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 4 buttons, which navigate to the Second screen
on Second Screen it will show the Button id and the timestamp

here's my code

```
 val button_one: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_one)
 button_one.setOnClickListener { buttonPressed(button_one) }
 val button_two: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_two)
 button_two.setOnClickListener { buttonPressed(button_two) }
 val button_three: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_three)
 button_three.setOnClickListener { buttonPressed(button_three) }
 val button_four: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_four)
 button_four.setOnClickListener { buttonPressed(button_four) }
}

private fun buttonPressed(button: Button) {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm aa")
    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

SecondActivity

```
 val textView_buttonPressed: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView_buttonPressed)
    val event_buttonPressed: TextView = findViewById(R.id.event_buttonPressed)
    val buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", buttonId)
    val timestamp = intent.getStringExtra("timestamp")

    textView_buttonPressed.text = "Button Id: $buttonId"
    event_buttonPressed.text = "Timestamp: $timestamp"
```

How to show on the Second Screen the Button id?

it should be like this..
[image]

Comment: you can also do this with recyclerview in an easier way

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `buttonPressed` function to include the timestamp and send it to the second activity as an intent extra:

```
 private fun buttonPressed() {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm aa", Locale.getDefault())
    val timestamp = format.format(Date()) // Get the current timestamp

    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("buttonId", R.id.button_one) // Pass the button ID to the second activity
    intent.putExtra("timestamp", timestamp) // Pass the timestamp to the second activity
    startActivity(intent)

    Log.d("Button", "Button 1 Tapped")
    Log.d("Event", timestamp)
}
```

second activity, retrieve the extras from the intent and display them:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

    val buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", 0)
    val timestamp = intent.getStringExtra("timestamp")

    buttonIdTextView.text = "Button ID: $buttonId"
    timestampTextView.text = "Timestamp: $timestamp"
}
```

Layout XML files (activity_main.xml and activity_second.xml)

Comment: I'll try and will let you know

Comment: Bro not working, it should be like Button 1 Tapped, Button 3 Tapped

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve that:

```
val buttonOne: Button = findViewById(R.id.button_one)
buttonOne.setOnClickListener { buttonPressed(buttonOne) }

// Similarly, set click listeners for button_two, button_three, and button_four

private fun buttonPressed(button: Button) {
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm aa")
    val timestamp = format.format(Date())

    val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("buttonId", button.id)
    intent.putExtra("timestamp", timestamp)
    startActivity(intent)

    Log.d("Button", "Button ${button.id} Tapped")
    Log.d("Event", timestamp)
}
```

In your buttonPressed function, you pass the clicked button (buttonOne, buttonTwo, etc.) to the function, and within the function, you extract the button ID using button.id. You also generate the timestamp using the SimpleDateFormat as before.

Make sure that your SecondActivity retrieves the data from the intent and displays it appropriately. For example, in the onCreate method of your SecondActivity, you can do something like:

```
val buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", -1)
val timestamp = intent.getStringExtra("timestamp")

// Now you can use these values to display in your UI or perform any other actions
```

Comment: it should be like Button 1 Tapped, or Button 3 Tapped

Comment: In your SecondActivity:
`
val textView_buttonPressed: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView_buttonPressed)
val event_buttonPressed: TextView = findViewById(R.id.event_buttonPressed)

val buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("buttonId", -1)
val timestamp = intent.getStringExtra("timestamp")

val buttonLabel = "Button $buttonId Tapped"

textView_buttonPressed.text = buttonLabel
event_buttonPressed.text = "Timestamp: $timestamp"
` you are using the buttonId you pass from the first activity to create dynamic label.